# MongoDB aggregate function with find function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, coffeescript

I am using coffeescript with nodejs to query monogodb data but for some custom data i need to perform aggregate function on my collection but using Session.aggregate(query) in the code is giving me error like not pipeline operator $and. So, i was thinking if can we integrate the aggregate func with the find method of monoogo.. any clue?

Query which i have defined in coffee-script is:

```
query = {
          $and : [ 
            { $match : { product: req.body.product } },
            { $project: { "_id": 1, totalHourSpent:{ $subtract: [ "$end_date", "$start_date" ] }}}
          ]
  }
```

Working fine while executing in the mongo shell but giving error while fetching the data with the coffee-script.

Comment: Have you tried running it with just `query = [ 
            { $match : { product: req.body.product } },
            { $project: { "_id": 1, totalHourSpent:{ $subtract: [ "$end_date", "$start_date" ] }}}
          ]`?

Comment: Query does not works and returns result as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax for aggregates in MongoDB wrong.

It should be an array, not an object passed to the `aggregate` method.
The [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) shows this in an example and links you to the official [mongo documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) as it's the same syntax.

You cannot use `$and` as a top level operator in an aggregate. You can use it inside a `$match` operator. But you cannot use it to combine a `$match` and `$project`. These are two separate steps in the pipeline and are done in sequence. There is no need for an `$and` operator in your query.

```
query = [
  {  
    $match : { 
      product: req.body.product 
      } 
  }, {
    $project: { 
      "_id": 1, 
      totalHourSpent: { 
        $dateDiff: [ "$end_date", "$start_date" ] 
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If this doesn't work, then please provide us with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing your Schema, an example document in the collection, the code surrounding this aggregate call and the request data being sent to the server.

Comment: I tried with this but didn't get any result in the response.

Comment: Please check my recent answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
query = [ { $match : { product: req.body.product } },
          { $project: { "_id": 1, totalHourSpent:{ $subtract: [ "$end_date", "$start_date" ] }}}          
  ]
  Session.aggregate(query)
  .exec((err, session) ->
    if err
      res.json err
      return 
    
    count = 0
    session.forEach () ->
        count = count + 1

    res.json count
```

count var just to check the no of response which i get but it returns 0 always.

NOTE: The query is working correctly in the Robo3T when running directly.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code example above?
You never close your parenthesis on the `exec` query and having all that `if err res.json err return` on one line is a syntax error

Comment: Indentation is correct in the code, here is just due to copy paste. If indentation was wrong i would not have been able to use the code to get the response.

Comment: But for me to help you I need to see the code exactly as you see it. Indentation matters in coffeescript so please make sure it exactly matches your code

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: I tried returning the session object also but it returns an empty object.

Comment: Thank you for that update.
Your code looks correct. My only remaining guess is that `req.body.product` is sent up incorrectly. Can you log it and check?

Comment: It's correct i have checked